# DialogBox causes app to crash.

Tags: android, mysql, json

**BEFORE WE START**

Firstly, let me start off by saying that this is my first Android app, and I am clueless. So if there is any approach that is stupid or not worth the effort, please let me know.

**PROBLEM**

I am building an app that ties in with a MySQL database that is hosted on a web server somewhere in the world of web servers. This app scan's a bar-code that we have attached to all of our assets, and these bar-codes link to an asset register that has all the details on that asset. The data will be sent as a JSON response.

I'm doing the app piece by piece. The scanner part I already have done, thanks to this guide. However, I now want to display a dialog window (mostly because I do not have any idea how to make the app just move over to a new window) with the info of that asset. At the moment, I'm struggling to get the dialog to open. As soon as it finishes scanning, the app crashes.

**CODE**

This is the bit of code that runs if I don't have the dialog box, but crashes if I do.

```
PreviewCallback previewCb = new PreviewCallback() {
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

        Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
        barcode.setData(data);

        int result = scanner.scanImage(barcode);

        if (result != 0) {
            previewing = false;
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.stopPreview();

            SymbolSet syms = scanner.getResults();
            for (Symbol sym : syms) {
                scanText.setText("barcode result " + sym.getData());
                barcodeScanned = true;

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getBaseContext());
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
                dialog.setTitle("Asset Details");
                TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
                text.setText("Details to go here with the image");
                ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            dialog.show();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**QUESTION**

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I have no idea what. So this is a 2 part question:

1. Would it be easier to make the app switch over to a new 'page' to display data? If so, how would I do this (a tutorial or something might help)?
2. What am I doing wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getBaseContext());
```

You need an `Activity` context for showing dialogs. `getBaseContext()` is almost always the wrong context to use, anyway.

Comment: How do I get an activity context?

Comment: @DarkRanger Is that code in your Activity then give YourActivityName.this as a Context.

Comment: @RaJeNdRa, yes it is in my activity. I'll try that now.

Answer (score 2):

Is that code in your Activity then give YourActivityName.this as a Context.

Change this from:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getBaseContext());
```

to

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivityName.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getBaseContext());
```

to this:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourACtivityName.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

you simply put here your class_name.this

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(class_name.this);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Application is also an incorrect context to use with dialogs.